# network connection works only once

Tags: networking, ssh, port-forwarding, tcp, telnet

I have setup a home server and did port forwarding for http/ssh/tcp etc on the router. It was working well until very recently. My problem is that now connections seem to work only once from outside my network for some reason.

```
 $ telnet xxxx 80
 Trying xxxx...
 Connected to x.
 Escape character is '^]'.
```

And right after I did this, if I try again, it gets stuck

```
 $ telnet xxxx 80
 Trying xxxx...
```

From a machine on the local network, there is no problem. 
All ports I have open have similar issues. I have also tried restarting/disabling firewalls on the router and the server machine.
Not having ssh capability to my machine from out of network is especially very problematic.

What could be the problem?

Thanks.

Comment: well, I've used Fail2Ban in past, and that kind of thing would blacklist your IP in IPtables if you probed the port with telnet a couple times. do you have any fancy logic surrounding the firewalling of your port? what happens if you use an actual client to connect?

Comment: The same thing happens with an actual client (an app) -- the reason why I started testing with telent is to take the app out of the equation. I allow access from anywhere for those ports using ufw service. I also tried disabling that to no avail.

Comment: Sound like a bad router to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out my ISP had "advanced security" setting activated without my knowledge. It makes sense now why it connects once, since it takes 30 sec for the block to take effect.